# Place FAB Button Over The Map With Coordinator And NestedScroolView

Tags: android, google-maps, floating-action-button

I would put my FAB on the map
I tried this code but does not work.

**My xml file is composed of:**

Coordinatorlayout tha including AppBarLayout
 
that including CollapsingToolbarLayout
 
that including ImageView

After use a NestedScrollView With LinearLayout
 
that including A map (com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment)
 
to follow a
FloatingActionButton.
 

The result is that the FAB is under the Map, and to move the NestedScrollView, i a "tapping" on the bottom.

I use API19 and Android Supporto Design Library, with Android Studio 1.5.

*Sorry for the English.*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Start second parts of layout NestedScrollView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="0dp">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

EDIT1 - UPDATE CODE

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="0dp">

            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_fab_add"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you should add the FAB outside the nested scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You should put the **FAB** outside the **NestedScrollView**